# Was the Fatah-1 rocket system indigenously developed by Pakistan?

Tags: pakistan

[image]

- [Pakistan successfully test fires guided multi-launch rocket system ‘Fatah-1’](https://www.arabnews.pk/node/1916551/pakistan)

> Pakistan on Tuesday conducted a successful test flight of an **indigenously developed** guided multi-launch rocket system called Fatah-1, the Pakistani military said, capable of delivering a conventional warhead.

Pakistan military's ISPR says the same:

- [Pakistan conducted a successful test flight of the indigenously developed Fatah-1 (Guided Multi Launch Rocket System), capable of delivering a conventional Warhead](https://ispr.gov.pk/press-release-detail.php?id=6267).

At first glance it looks like a  Chinese A300:

[image]

Or, Belarusian Polonaize-M (which was developed from the Chinese A300):

[image]

Was the Fatah-1 rocket system indigenously developed by Pakistan or was it imported from China?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the name refers to the rocket, not the launcher? Then the outward similarity of carrier vehicles is irrelevant. On the other hand, Pakistan operates Chinese A-100 system, which A-200 and A-300 were developed from; Fatah-1 might be indigenously developed based on imported A-100 rocket design.

Comment: What do you mean by "indigenously developed"? It is going to use technology from other countries, in terms of components, manufacturing, and basic knowledge of rocketry. Is there some definition of "indigenously developed"?

Comment: @StuartF, You tell me. Coz, that term was not used by me, but them.

Comment: Could this be a translation issue?

Comment: @Schwern, No. By ***indigenous***, they mean ***home-grown***. I think, sometimes, they show Chinese ToT as home-grown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's probably an A-100 offshoot.

[According to globalsecurity.org](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/world/pakistan/fatah-1.htm)...

> Fearing India’s defense preparedness, ***Pakistan is teaming up with China*** to test new weapons with the Fatah-1 guided multiple-launch rocket system...
>
> According to Director General of Pakistan Army, Media Wing, Major General Babar Iftikhar, Fatah-1 weapon system can hit targets up to a range of 140 km. "The Weapon System will give Pakistan Army capability of precision target engagement deep in enemy territory," said Iftikhar. ***Pakistan has not shared any additional information on this rocket system...***
>
> Pakistan’s press reported that the Fatah-1 is indigenously developed and ***it seems likely that it is an evolutionary off shoot of the Chinese A-100 system that is in service with the Pakistan army***. This rocket is produced in Pakistan and has provided the country with useful experience in producing and utilising long-range rocket artillery systems.

## They previously claimed the A-100 was indigenous. It isn't.

[Inter Services Public Relations](https://ispr.gov.pk/), the media wing of the Pakistani military, [previously claimed](https://ispr.gov.pk/press-release-detail.php?id=5130) "*A-100 Rocket has been indigenously developed by Pakistani scientists and engineers*." The [A-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-100_(multiple_rocket_launcher)) is a Chinese rocket system which Pakistan purchased and produce locally, but it wasn't developed by Pakistani scientists and engineers as claimed.